# Tkinter image display with stretching

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to display an image in Tkinter. This image is saved on the disk as a jpg, and I can display it in matplotlib.pyplot for example without any troubles.

My trouble that only the first-pixel line/row is displayed, then it looks like it expanded to cover the image size.

Here is my code (ultra simple):

```
from Tkinter import *
import Image, ImageTk

root = Tk()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(r"test.JPG"))
panel = Label(root, image = img)
panel.image = img
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")

root.mainloop()
```

And here is the resulting image from "test":
[image: display image]
While the original image is:
[image: original image]

In case, I update PIL as well as Tk, but no change. Other pieces of code give the same result.
I am using python 2.7 on Windows 10.

Comment: Which of the images in your post is `test.JPG`?

Comment: @Bryan test.JPG is the original image, the one at the bottom.